# How to create iterator to solve this problem?

Tags: c++, search, boost, dictionary, set

So we have 3 maps. args, headers and params maps. They are string to string maps.
We also have a `set<settings> Settings_Set` where:

```
struct settings
{
    string name;  
    set<string> args;
    set<string> headers;
    set<string> params;
};
```

We want to compare all of our maps->first strings with all our sets in all items of Settings_Set.  After or while comparing we want to know

- if more than one of our sttings in Settings_Set were found in our maps
- if only one setting were found in our maps (and output its name)
- if none of our settings were found in maps

So how to create such thing?

Comment: Could you be more precise? I really don't understand the question and don't see any `map`s just `set`s.

Comment: Who's **we**? This is not a write-my-program-for-free service.

Comment: There is no magic pre-existing algorithm to solve your very specific problem. You'll have to loop through each setting in your set, do searches in your maps, and assign results to variables yourself. After you make your own attempt to write the program, we'll be happy to assist you if you run into problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need boost at all.  Also, I don't see any instances of `std::map` even though you call them "maps".  I only see sets.

This is not a solution *per se*, but more a hint to figuring it out. You can loop over the elements of `set<settings> Settings_Set` with:

```
set<settings>::iterator ite = Settings_Set.begin();

while(ite != Settings_Set.end())
{
// do what you need to do in here
// with the corresponding ite->name, ite->args, ite->headers, and ite->params

// Also, you can see if something is in a set by using:
// set<string>::iterator ites = ite->params.find(std::string("some string"));
// which will put the appropriate iterator into ites if one is found
// or ite->params.end() if one is not found

++ite;
}
```

You should be able to piece it together from this and from one of the standard references on `std::set`: [STL set reference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html)

(Note I didn't use `const_iterator` intentionally, because I'm assuming you might be changing the values, as you said in your post.)

Comment: I feel that this is just guesswork as long as the question is so vague.